# Test cases failed in paragraphs algorithm palindromes

Tags: c#, algorithm, testing

Good afternoon, I was conducting an exercise on [this](https://www.testdome.com/Questions/Csharp/Palindrome/4951?testId=21&testDifficulty=Easy) page, and I fail two test cases are these:

> Lowercase single word: Wrong answer
>
> Any case single word: Wrong answer

I can not understand, they mean me with that, because in the algorithm do, I control the upper and lower case.

My algorithm is as follows :

```
using System;

public class Palindrome
{
    public static char[] abecedario = new char[]{ 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','w','x','y','z'};
    public static char[] ABECEDARIO = new char[]{ 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','W','X','Y','Z'};

    public static bool IsPalindrome(string str)
    {
        string strOriginal = string.Empty;
        string strInversa = string.Empty;
        for(int i = str.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string concatenarInversa = string.Empty;
            string concatenarOriginal = string.Empty;
            for(int j = 0; j < abecedario.Length; j++)
            {
               if(str[i] == abecedario[j] || str[i] == ABECEDARIO[j])
               {
                   concatenarInversa = abecedario[j].ToString();
               }
               if(str[(str.Length-1)-i] == abecedario[j] || str[(str.Length-1)-i] == ABECEDARIO[j] )
               {
                    concatenarOriginal = abecedario[j].ToString();
               }
               if(concatenarInversa!=string.Empty && concatenarOriginal != string.Empty)
               {
                   break;
               }
            }
            if(concatenarInversa!=string.Empty)
            {
                strInversa = strInversa + concatenarInversa;
            }
            if(concatenarOriginal != string.Empty)
            {
                strOriginal = strOriginal + concatenarOriginal;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("strInversa : " + strInversa);
        Console.WriteLine("strOriginal : " + strOriginal);
        return strInversa == strOriginal;

    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsPalindrome("sEeS"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it in the debugger to see where the algorithm goes wrong?

Comment: if I do not understand what the problem is indicating me test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `abecedario` variables are missing the letter V (v). Try this:

```
public static char[] abecedario = new char[]{ 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
public static char[] ABECEDARIO = new char[]{ 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
```

or perhaps (easier to type):

```
public static char[] abecedario = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
public static char[] ABECEDARIO = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
```

For an example of a test your current code fails, consider the word "vee". It's not a palindrome, but because your code ignores the letter V, it believes that it is.